# Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед союзом "и"

Tags: однородные-члены

Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед и:

Я не хотела с ним сближаться, что-то о нем узнавать и запрещала себе о нем думать.

Comment: Hanu, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

*Я **не хотела** с ним **сближаться**, что-то о нем **узнавать** и **запрещала** себе о нем думать.*

Запятая не нужна, это простое предложение. Предикативная основа: Я не хотела сближаться, узнавать и запрещала.

Союз И связывает два сказуемых, причем первое составное глагольное сказуемое содержит однородные инфинитивы (связь бессоюзная, стоит запятая).

Comment: _Sharon: Предикативная основа: Не хотела сближаться, узнавать и запрещала._ === А где «Я»?

Comment: Не знаю куда делось.. Точно помню, что было  :)